# plotting stars in cartessian coordinates using the stars ra and dec produces the wrong location of the stars

Tags: star, coordinate

I am currently running into some problems with plotting some stars locations in a Cartesian coordinate system.
The stars aren't in the right order and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

I first use the equation (where S is a vector)

```
S = [cos(ra)*cos(dec), sin(ra)*cos(dec), sin(dec)]
```

to obtain a vector S of the star.
I now want to obtain the x and y positions of the stars In terms of a 2d coordinate system so I use

```
c * sx = S * px / S* pz
c * sy = S * py / S* pz
```

where C is the scale ratio of pixels to tangent of the angle of the camera and P is the vector center of the camera.(Im using this because I'm trying to find the distance between each pair of stars when a photo of the stars is taken by a camera)

```
px = unit vector X
py = unit vector Y
pz = unit vector Z
```

and I solve for sx and sy. When I plot the stars location with sx and sy however I do not get the right locations of the stars. Any guidance?

Comment: S is a scalar in this example. Is the code correct?

Comment: could you please clarify what is a vector, scalar, dot product etc. in your writing? This is extremely confusing and inconsistent

Comment: in this example S is a vector! My apologies I wasn't sure how to add the notations for vectors and dot products

Comment: This [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help.If $\hat{\mathrm p}_z= \vec P$, then your $\hat{\mathrm p}_x$ and $\hat{\mathrm p}_y$ look like my $\hat{\mathrm u}$ and $\hat{\mathrm v}$.

Answer (score 1):

A photograph of stars is essentially a
[gnomonic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection)
of part of the
[celestial sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere).
If $\vec P$ is computed for the photograph center (RA, Dec) in the same way as $\vec S$,
and the north celestial pole is
$\hat{\mathrm k} = (0, 0, 1)^{\mathrm T}$,
then the photograph has basis vectors perpendicular to $\vec P$ and each other,
$$\hat{\mathrm u} = \frac{\vec P \times \hat{\mathrm k}}{\| \vec P \times \hat{\mathrm k} \|},
\hat{\mathrm v} = \frac{\hat{\mathrm u} \times \vec P}{\| \hat{\mathrm u} \times \vec P \|}$$
and you can project $\vec S$ onto the photograph as
$$\left( \frac{\vec S \cdot \hat{\mathrm u}}{\vec S \cdot \vec P},
\frac{\vec S \cdot \hat{\mathrm v}}{\vec S \cdot \vec P} \right)$$
scaling as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! In my case, I am using vector P as (1, 1, 1) however im not sure if I should be doing this. Would k hat be apart of the vector P or is a seperate value on its own where I should be using its value as the center? Would you also be able to provide any links to where I might be able to learn more about this concept.

Comment: $\vec P$ depends on the region of interest, e.g. for the Big Dipper you might center the photo at RA 12 h, Dec +55 deg and use $\vec P$ = (-0.57, 0.0, 0.82). To make $\hat{\mathrm u}$ and $\hat{\mathrm v}$  point west and north in the photo, I used a cross product with [standard basis vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) $\hat{\mathrm k}$ (aligned with +Z axis, north celestial pole).

Comment: so if I were to have kept my P vector as (1 , 1 , 1), this would have given me incorrect results for finding the coordinates of the stars in the big dipper?

Comment: You might still be able to plot them, but the constellation would be severely distorted.